# Need to add resposive grid elements inside website with html text editor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically i need to add few responsive grid elements inside website, i only have access to html text editor..

I tried one way, to link bootstrap css, it worked, but problem is it messed up other webpage elements as well.

So im running out of ideas how to do this hackjob..

Another thing, i cant upload css to that website server (css file uploading is blocked in html text editor), so i can either link or use inline style css.

Any ideas of how i should this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDN of the Bootstrap Grid only. Then none of your other elements will be changed from the other Bootstrap CSS.

**Bootstrap 4 Grid:**
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap-grid.css

Comment: That was good suggestion but even the bootstrap-grid alone manages to mess up some elements as well

Comment: What elements? It shouldn't mess with anything as it only has code that affects elements with Bootstrap grid classes like .container, .row etc.

Comment: nav meniu items, nav, nav-list and sub-nav sub-nav-service.